# How to make a disabled select box look like a normal text box(css only)

Tags: css, disabled-control

I tried to change the inline css of the select box as below

```
.chosen-disabled .chosen-single {
  cursor: default;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #444; 
}
```

The select box appeared to be faded but I need it to be look like a normal text field(but still disabled).

Please help me here and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank @Christoph and @Carine, i override the chose disable class by giving inline css as

```
.chosen-disabled {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

now its working fine, thanks once again for your support.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the disabled CSS selector.

```
input[type="text"]:disabled {
    background: #dddddd;
}
```

Demo:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/bronni/ar1qoznj/

Comment: Thanks, I am using chose plugin for select boxes, if i use only 'chosen-single' class then its working fine.but here my field has  'chosen-select fields' class due to which changes are not taking place.

Comment: You can use `select:disabled` for select all select box. Independent to the classes.

Comment: :Thanks once again for your quick reply, i tried this one also but its doesn't make any changes.

Comment: Demo with other and none class elements [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/bronni/ar1qoznj/3/). understand I the problem correctly?

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/o5xs7e6u/)

I am not 100% if this is what you are looking for but it seems to work based off what you stated you wanted (the text is red when disabled is applied)

CSS:

```
select {
  cursor: default;
  color: #000;
  border: 3px solid #444; 
}

select.disabled {
    color:red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<select disabled class="disabled">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks , i have already tried this but here i want field color to be black. when i given 'color:black', its appearing as gray.